# Javascript TypeError, function is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

Ok, so I'm learning Javascript and for my first small project I want to make a task organizer. When I click the button the first time to add a task it adds it to the page, and then when I click the button to add another task it throws a type error. Do I need some kind of loop to catch the error or is the problem calling the function when the button is clicked?

Error

```
ToDo.html:12 Uncaught TypeError: getTask is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (ToDo.html:12)
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <p>Task Tracker</p>
        <input type="text" name="Title" id="taskInput">
        <button onclick="getTask()"> Add Task </button>
        <div class="todo" id="showTask">    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javasript

```
var getTask;
var task;
function getTask(){
    getTask = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;
    task = getTask;
    console.log(task);
    document.getElementById('showTask').innerHTML = task;
}
```

Comment: Where is the script being included in the HTML?

Comment: You can't have a global function and a global variable with the same name.

Comment: The javascript is linked in the bottom of the head and looks like this

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>

Comment: I didnt realize I named the variable the same as the function name haha, But I changed that and now when I press the button it will work everytime but instead of adding a new task to the page, the new task entered takes the place of the old one.

Comment: Yes because you reassign the `.innerHTML` of the container element. That replaces all of the former content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote into the comment you named the variable the same way that you named your function. You actually don't need to initialise the variable outside of the function. For your second question in the comment, your variable becomes the new task because you actually do replace the whole content of the variable. You need to use an array instead.

```
var task = [];
function getTask(){
    var getTask = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;
    task.push(getTask);
    console.log(task);
    document.getElementById('showTask').innerHTML = task;
}
```

See the first line `var task = [];` and the fourth line `task.push(getTask);`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. And is it right to assume that the .push() method is like python append method?

Comment: yes that is correct. Check out this for infos on arrays https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

getTask is declared as a Function not a global variable

```js
// getTask is a function not declare as global variable
        var task;
        function getTask(){
            task = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;;
            console.log(task);
            document.getElementById('showTask').innerHTML = task;
        }
```

```html
 <div class='container'>
        <p>Task Tracker</p>
        <input type="text" name="Title" id="taskInput">
        <button onclick="getTask()"> Add Task </button>
        <div class="todo" id="showTask">    
        </div>
    </div>
```